# Image no longer responsive as put in table cell layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to center an image on a site. As I want it to be centered both horizontally and vertically I used a table/table-cell layout as following:

```
<div id="mainContainer>
    <div id="horizon">
        <img src="url">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here mainContainer ist set to *display: table* and horizon is set to *display: table-cell*.

Unfortunately the image is no longer resizing proportionally as it becomes part of this structure. As soon as I move it into the table/table-cell divs it resizes to its original size (instead of being resized proportionally because of *max-width: 100%* and *max-height: 100%*)

see: http://jsfiddle.net/U8KcN/

**EDIT:**

> My bad. I just tried to simplify the issue. I want to build a little slideshow for images. The problem here is that I do not know which sizes the images are (referring to someone else using the slideshow). So in simple terms I need a specific CSS that 1) centers the image vertically and horizontally in the div if its width and height are smaller than the div's dimensions, 2) resizes the image automatically if it is bigger than the div's dimensions (unnecessary to add, it is unknown whether it's width or height is bigger).

*source: [OP Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345596/image-no-longer-responsive-as-put-in-table-cell-layout#comment25232453_17345836)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about dropping that "CSS-table" stuff and doing it a bit easier?

```
<div style="width:auto;height:auto;margin:25%;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">
     <img src="URL">
</div>
```

At least, that’s how I would handle it...

**EDIT:**

Please note that I've put the CSS inline to show you what element should get what style. In production, you should — as a comment to this answer correctly stated — always separate style from code like. So, practically, you'll end up with something like this:

```
<style>
.centerimg {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin:25%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle
}
</style>

...

<div class="centerimg">
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Replying to the related comment, here's the update to make the image fit it's parent proportionally:

If your image has a bigger width than height...

```
<style>
...
img{
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto
}
</style>
```

or, if your image has a smaller width than height...

```
<style>
...
img{
   max-height:100%;
   width:auto
}
</style>
```

**EDIT 3:**

Looking at your fiddle, I came up with this which works like you want it to work:

```
<style>
*{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle
}

img{
width:auto;
height:100%;
}
</style>
```

I've forked your fiddle to show the updates: http://jsfiddle.net/LPrkb/1/

**EDIT 3:**

As the OP doesn't seem to be able to decide what he needs, I'm adding this final edit due to his latest comment.

You could also use a CSS background-image with "background-size:contain" on the "mainContainer" and be done with it... check http://jsfiddle.net/HGpfJ/2/ or look at this 100% working example taking a completely different approach which results in just the same effect/functionality:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<style>
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
#centerimg{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:transparent url(http://oi42.tinypic.com/v9g8i.jpg) no-repeat scroll center;
background-size:contain;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="centerimg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's face the facts: depending on where in the document structure you want to have the image "centered", there are more than a dozen of ways to do it.

If OP needs specific code, we will need the complete document structure from OP and not simply a *"generalized"* code-snippet which could be anywhere in whatever document structure.

Comment: With the addendum that the CSS shouldn't be inline.

Comment: @RyanKinal That's logic... and we completely think the same when it comes to that! The only reason I coded the CSS inline is to make it obvious what element should get what style, instead of using multiple paragraphs to explain it. ;)

Comment: @RyanKinal Added an "edit" to the answer to implement your correct addendum. Thanks for the heads-up to make my reply a bit more complete.

Comment: Your suggestion is not quite what I wanted. I'm looking for a no-scroll (overflow: hidden) solution where the image is resized (proportionally) to fit its parent div.
( Your solution looks like http://jsfiddle.net/TD7RU/ )

Comment: And the addendum that `vertical-align: center` doesn't exist.

Comment: @ШтефанСуркамп Added "EDIT 2" to take care of the image fitting it's parent upon resizing to whatever dimension...

Comment: @ШтефанСуркамп Ok, I've forked your fiddle to show you my EDIT 3 in action. Does what you want it to do.

Comment: @e-sushi: Yup, works just fine for images that are bigger than the div box... but if I'm using a smaller one the div box shrinks to the image size and furthermore the image is no longer centered vertically (inside the box)?

Comment: @ШтефанСуркамп We can play this back and forth, because - depending on the real page code you are using, and depending on the placement of the element itself in the document structure - things will have to be coded specifically to suit your needs. For that, I would need to know what image sizes you would be expecting, and I would need to know where in the document structure you're wanting to position the image. See, there are many options. In fact, you could also use a CSS background-image with "background-size:contain" on the "mainContainer" and be done with it... http://jsfiddle.net/HGpfJ/2/

Comment: @ШтефанСуркамп I have added a last "edit" (number 3!) to my reply. Unless you provide the actual code, this is the best I can do for you.

Comment: My bad. I just tried to simplify the issue. I want to build a little slideshow for images. The problem here is that I do not know which sizes the images are (referring to someone else using the slideshow). So in simple terms I need a specific CSS that 1) centers the image vertically and horizontally in the div if its width and height are smaller than the div's dimensions, 2) resizes the image automatically if it is bigger than the div's dimensions (unnecessary to add, it is unknown whether it's width or height is bigger).

Comment: @ШтефанСуркамп Well, for a "slideshow" you'll probably want to use javascript sooner or later. Besides the options I've showed you above, you can get similar results using javascript itself... which can be used to scale images depending on the size of the slideshow parent element, and javascript can handle the show/hide functionality of your "slideshow". I know there are a lot of ready-to-use examples out on the web. My best advice would be to check out "jquery" and find a "jquery slideshow plugin" that looks comfortable to you. It's the easiest way if you're not a javascript coder. #My2Cents

Comment: @e-sushi: Thanks for your response. Sure, I'm already using Javascript and the jQuery library, but I want to build this plugin from scratch for (self) educational reasons. I just thought: Why calculate each and every margin if there's a native CSS solution? Thanks for your thoughts anyway, seems like there is no "simple solution" to this issue.

Comment: @ШтефанСуркамп Well, then all that's left to do is to accept the answer you think is the most usable to you.

Answer (score 7):

Every time I hear someone talk about the evils of using tables and then see them create a complete table structure out of DIVs with pretty much the same amount of markup -- sometimes more -- it really gets on my nerves.

By the way, have you ever developed a site for someone who wanted to do some of their own layouts in the content area using a CMS like Wordpress? The only way someone with almost no HTML knowledge can do that well is by allowing them to use table tools in Tiny MCE or another editor. So yes, tables are still important.

Recently, I had to do just that for a customer, but the images in the table cells were not responding and shrinking for smaller screen sizes. All I had to add to my CSS to care of that problem was:

```
table {

   table-layout: fixed; 

}
```

Now the images in the table cells are growing and shrinking accordingly, and the horizontal scrollbar is no longer appearing. Oh, of course you have to use percentages in your table width and td widths as well.

Comment: Also, outlook compatible e-mails require a responsive table layout.

Answer (score 2):

Using tables (`display: table-cell`) for layout is a web development anti-pattern these days. Try using the `<span>` element with `display: inline-block` to vertically and horizontally center the image, as this method will [work all the way back to IE 6](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html). Also, you can change the image size to be a percentage if you want it to resize according to its container:

http://jsfiddle.net/hHWy8/1/

HTML:

```
<span class="horizontal">
    <span class="vertical">
        <img src="url" />
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.horizontal {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
span.vertical {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black; /* put a border on container for display purposes */
    line-height: 1000px;     /* this sets the vertical height */
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
span.vertical img {
    height: 50px; /* set your image height (could be percent) */
    width: 50px;  /* set your image width (could be percent) */
}
span.vertical br {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: To me it seems the image is just shrinked to the specified values. But I want it to resize proportionally (if it is bigger than its container). Elsewise I want it to be centered in the parent container.

Comment: @ШтефанСуркамп If you want it to resize proportionally you can use percentages (`%`) instead of pixels (`px`).

Comment: As mentioned above, I do not know in advance if the image fits the container, if it is bigger in width, in height, or in both.

Answer (score 1):

To resize your image you could use this css:

```
    html,body,div,img{
        height:100%;
    }

    img { width:100%}
```

It sets the html and body's height to 100%, this is needed so the height of your page takes all available space

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know whether the image's dimensions are smaller  or bigger than the div's one. See my response to @e-sushi's answer above.